# Como um protocolo SSL/TLS pode proteger um site?

Tags: segurança, http, https

É uma dúvida muito antiga, porém ainda não tinha parado para pesquisar sobre, fiz uma rápida pesquisa e não achei nada de útil que explicasse: *Como HTTPS protege um site?*

A pergunta é razoavelmente simples para quem entende sobre.